# Error installing Kotlin plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, plugins

I want to install a plugin for Kotlin support in Eclipse but it keeps me giving errors. This is the screenshot of the error:

[image: This is the screenshot of the error]

I have 2 more plugins, PyDev and jar files.

Error details:

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Kotlin 1.5.31.120211018-0606 (Org.jetbrains.kotlib.feature.feature.group 1.5-31-V20211018-060 Missing requirement: kotlin-eclipse-ui 1.5-31.120211018-0606 (Org.jetbrains.kotiin.ui 1.5.31.V20211018-0606) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui o..' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Kotlin 1.5.31.20211018-0606 (Org.jetbrains.kotlin feature feature.group, 1.5.31.120211018-0606) To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui (1.5.31.202110180606,1-5.31-V20211018-0606]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like it wants some mylyn plug-ins which are not included in Eclipse anymore - but the image is hard to read because of the very strange font.

Comment: Im installing a plugin from eclipse marketplace in order to write code in Kotlin. But the thing is, when im trying to install it, it give me an error. Sometimes a repository is not found. In short, i want to install this *plugin*. Hope that clarifies it

Comment: What version/release/download are you trying to install Kotlin *into*? And have you tried the support options for the Marketplace entry?

Comment: Try adding `https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/` to the "Install/Update > Available Software Sites" list in the Preferences